# PreSaveItem() function not firing for save on XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, save

I have 2 web parts on the page, a `DataFormWebPart` and a `XsltListViewWebPart`. I'm trying to do some custom validation for the `XsltListViewWebPart` and would like to do it on the `presave` event.

Currently I am using `PreSaveAction()` to do some validation on the `DataFormWebPart` and this works fine. I have tried the `PreSaveAction()` and `PreSaveItem()` events for the `XsltListViewWebPart` however neither one gets fired. Does anyone know if there is a `presave` event on a `XsltListViewWebPart`?

I've looked at the XML for the `XsltListViewWebPart` and there doesn't seem to a straight forward way to edit the save button JavaScript either. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually saving? In a Data form web part you can edit and save an individual item. An XLV shows a list of items. Where does saving come in?

Comment: I'm saving per item in the XLV web part where a user can edit one item at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom form action button or the default save button?

If you are using a custom form action button then you need to add the PreSaveAction manually.

```
<a id="savebutton" href="javascript: if (PreSaveAction()) {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;dvt_1_form_insertmode={1}')}"  style="">Save and View</a>
```

Comment: It's the default save button on the XsltListViewWebPart which saves per item. I've looked at the XML for the web part and can't see where the save/delete buttons are created.

Comment: Can you post your PreSaveAction() code?

Comment: `function PreSaveAction() {
    var isAllValid = false;
    isAllValid = ValidateMandatoryfields();
    return isAllValid;
}` This works however isn't fired on the save event of the XSLTListViewWebPart save button.